# C# Creating a lot of instances of one object with a name in a string

Tags: c#

I am trying to load some info from .txt file and then create an instance of a class... I need to create new instance for each line in the .txt file and I would like to name each instace in order. First line in .txt file would create and instance called card1, another line would create instace called card2... There is really a lot of lines in the .txt file so I need this process to be automated, but this, what i made doesn't work, because it seems that I cannot use string as a name of the instance... Is there something which would solve this problem? Thanks for your help...

```
Console.WriteLine("Loading cards from .txt file");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"G:\Temp\cards.txt"))
{
    string s;
    int cardIndex = 1;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string cardName = "card" + cardIndex.ToString();
        Card cardName = new Card(s)
        cardIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your "Card" class code? Also keep in mind that you are passing line value to Card instead of CardName and creating a class with same variable name as previous.

Comment: What is `Card`? Why doesn't it work? I hope you don't mean to use `card123` as _variable_ name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the same name for both the `Card` and `string` variables.

```
Console.WriteLine("Loading cards from .txt file");
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"G:\Temp\cards.txt"))
{
    string s;
    int cardIndex = 1;
    Dictionary<string, Card> d = new Dictionary<string, Card>();

    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string cardName = "card" + cardIndex.ToString();
        Card card = new Card(cardName, s);
        d.Add(s, card);

        cardIndex++;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass `cardName`, `s` and whatever you want to `card` according to the constructors you have/ class's implementation.

To access it use whichever way of accessing a value in a dictionary that you like: via `[]` or `TryGet` like others specified.

---

Though this will solve your problem I'd suggest quite some refactoring to the code. I'd go for the way @Dmitry suggested (with the linq) if you are at that level and understand what is going on.

It is a nice and elegant way of having the `index` and of creating these objects for each `line` - Upvote from me

Answer (score 2):

Try *Linq*:

```
Card[] deck = File 
    .ReadLines(@"G:\Temp\cards.txt") 
    .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    .Select((line, index) => new Card(string.Format("card{0}", index + 1), line))
    .ToArray(); // technically, materialization is not necessary
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class Card needs a property with the name. You could use the "name" to  override your ToString(). Have a look at this example:

```
public class Card
{
  public readonly string Name;
  public readonly string S;

  public Card(string Name, string S)
  {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.S = S;
  }

  public override ToString()
  {
    return Name;
  }
}
```

Now you could create a card in your loop with

```
Card NewCard = new Card(cardName, s);
```